# How do I correct the position of my robot in this diagram? Having a hard time visualizing the formulas needed

Tags: geometry

Okay, so say that I have a robot which travels in a grid of tiles. Between each tile is a black line. At both sides of my robot is a light sensor. The robot only travels to adjacent tiles. Knowing that my robot's movement is definitely not going to be perfect, I want to implement a way of correcting its position. I'm having a hard time picturing how this should be done though.

Say the robot is travelling in the y direction

What we know:

- The robot will think the y position is the only one that's changing
- If both light sensors detect the black line at the same time, then we know that the robot is moving straight (image to the left)
- If the robot detects the line with the right light sensor first at y = a, and detects the line with the left light sensor afterwards at y = a + b, then we know the difference between the detections was b (image to the right)
- We also know the distance from one light sensor to the other

Now with this knowledge, what information can I obtain so that I can correct the robot's position and then have it re-call the travel(x,y) so that it can turn to the proper heading needed instead of continuing straight at an off-angle.

Thanks for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The distance between sensors, and the distance measured are at a right angle from each other. So to measure the small angle we use tan^(-1)(b/distance)